# Normalization of signal against reference

Tags: image-processing, time-series, normalization

I am trying to figure out if there is any standard way of normalizing a sequence such as a time series against a reference sequence. I am not an expert on signal processing but I was hoping someone would be able to point out a good way of doing this. Specifically, I am working on image analysis where I measure pixel intensities along linescans. This gives me two intensity profiles along space (from 2 channels). I am trying to normalize 1 channel against the 2nd one (reference).

Comment: Normalize to equal energy, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your reference image data `y_reference` is acquired when there is no light on the image sensor - that's the standard thing to do. Then the usual normalized signal is
`y_normalized = (y_signal - y_reference) / y_max`
where `y_signal` is the signal image data and `y_max` is the maximum possible pixel output. `y_max` can be measured by increasing the light level on the image sensor until the output no longer increases.